# Create measure to calculate % change from distinct values in a column

Tags: powerbi, dax

**Situation:**

I have a column in my table with values representing weeks of the year.
Each week number has their respective total counts of purchases on another column. When I use a matrix visual and put that specific column in the Columns section it separates them distinctively which is what I want. How can get the % change from one week to another?

Table looks like this:

[image]

**Objective:**

Create a measure that can divides column 2 by column 1 to get the % change.

**Layout of Matrix:**

[image]

Ideally I would like to have a third column to calculate the values in column 6 by the ones in column 5.

Comment: The way you structured your table makes this quite tricky. Is there a reason you need it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here is one solution:

```
Delta := 
VAR Week5 =
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[Total] ), FILTER ( 'Table', 'Table'[Weeks] = 5 ) )
VAR Week6 =
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[Total] ), FILTER ( 'Table', 'Table'[Weeks] = 6 ) )
RETURN
    IF (
        SUM ( 'Table'[Total] ) = SUMX ( ALL ( 'Table' ), 'Table'[Total] )
            || SUM ( 'Table'[Total] )
                = SUMX (
                    FILTER ( ALL ( 'Table' ), 'Table'[Cohort] = MAX ( 'Table'[Cohort] ) ),
                    'Table'[Total]
                ),
        100*DIVIDE ( Week6 - Week5, Week5 ),
        BLANK ()
    )
```

I tested it and it works:

### [image]

BUT because the way your data is structured, it makes it very difficult (for me) to make this pretty. But hey, it works!! ;) I wasn't sure which direction you needed the delta but that is a simple change in the measure from this:

```
100*DIVIDE ( Week6 - Week5, Week5 )
```

To this:

```
100*DIVIDE ( Week5 - Week6, Week6 )
```

Hope this help!